# What is the most simple way to assign an icon to my program?

Tags: c++, windows-xp, icons

Here is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I have my hello.ico file too. What I wish to do is compile my program (in codelite) to run in Windows XP with the hello.ico as it's icon.

How do I achieve this in the most simple way?

Comment: Icons are referenced in _resource files_ (file ending ".rc") which are compiled with a special compiler and then linked to the executable.

Comment: Console mode apps don't have icons.  You can assign an arbitrary icon to the desktop shortcut when you create it.

Comment: @HansPassant: That's more a matter of convention than anything else. Explorer doesn't check whether your EXE would start as a console app; if there's a icon resource then it will be shown.

Comment: I'm talking about the one on the upper left corner of the title bar.

Comment: Ah, I was talking about the one shown in Explorer. @Ants: which Icon did you mean? @HansPassant: i'm not sure what would happen if you'd send the console window a `WM_SETICON`.

Comment: @MSalters The icon displayed in, say, Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write your program as VC++ in visual studio. the C++ code will work fine and in the resource folder you can set icon, draw or edit icon